# Parse-Server maxUploadSize

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, amazon-s3, parse-server

So i have setup parse-server, specifically [parse-server-example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) on Heroku with mLab db and s3 file adapter for storage.

Ive been scouring GitHub and stack overflow trying to find a solution to the maxUploadSize limitations.

By default this is set to '20mb' and sources say that you can modify this option to be anything you like.  Within my parse-server-example there are 4 files that contain this variable:

```
 1. ParseServer.js
/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib
 2. FilesRouter.js
/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib/Routers
 3.parse-server.js
/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib/cli/definitions
 3. index.js
/parse-server-example
 4. defaults.js
/parse-server-example/node_modules/parse-server/lib
```

I have replaced all instances of '20mb' with '100mb' in these 4 files and have added the maxUploadSize option variable to my index.js file.  I think the only place where this matters is the index.js file.  This is where i changed it originally and it did allow larger files, i then changed it in the other locations out of desperation and there has been no change in the result.

index.js:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    //**** General Settings ****//

databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  
maxUploadSize: '100mb',
```

Now i can upload files upto 40mb quite easily, but when i try upload anything larger it shows as uploading in the dashboard for quite a while then just stops.

I have also read that setting the client_max_body_size in .ebextensions may play a part but i think this is for elastic beanstalk on aws so don't think its relevant for me.  Though i even tried adding the variable in a files.config file inside the .ebextensions folder in my /parse-server-example/ folder.

I am uploading files through the parse dashboard so they are then transferred to the s3bucket i have setup with the unique PFFIle name.

This is what my Heroku logs look like after trying a 50mb upload:

```
2017-02-06T06:58:14.188932+00:00 app[web.1]: } method=POST, url=/parse/classes/Part, host=parse-server-example.herokuapp.com, connection=close, content-type=text/plain, origin=http://0.0.0.0:4040, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, accept=*/*, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.2 Safari/602.3.12, referer=http://0.0.0.0:4040/apps/parse-server-example/browser/Part, accept-language=en-au, x-request-id=df8ecd66-76f5-4592-9c82-44a86f6c4165, x-forwarded-for=101.165.231.37, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=1, x-request-start=1486364292657, total-route-time=0, content-length=235, __op=Delete
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210449+00:00 app[web.1]: [36mverbose[39m: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/classes/Part: {
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210451+00:00 app[web.1]:   "status": 201,
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210452+00:00 app[web.1]:   "response": {
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210453+00:00 app[web.1]:     "objectId": "vrIuYJCOfG",
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210455+00:00 app[web.1]:     "createdAt": "2017-02-06T06:58:14.190Z"
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210456+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210457+00:00 app[web.1]:   "location": "https://parse-server-example.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/Part/vrIuYJCOfG"
2017-02-06T06:58:14.210459+00:00 app[web.1]: } status=201, objectId=vrIuYJCOfG, createdAt=2017-02-06T06:58:14.190Z, location=https://parse-server-example.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/Part/vrIuYJCOfG
2017-02-06T06:58:29.061410+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/parse/files/South%20Park%20s09e02%20-%20Die%20Hippie,%20Die%20_%20480p%20UNCENSORED%20x264%20NIT158.mp4" host=parse-server-example.herokuapp.com request_id=0e76d848-3c8a-44e5-8efe-4d586ced8e8a fwd="111.111.111.11" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=477
```

It seems to show everything as bytes=447 regardless of actual size?

There is another version of [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) on GitHub that has a different FilesRouter.js file and others but they look to be the development master.

I am wondering if it may be advised to overwrite my existing setup with this one, if so how to do it without stuffing up what I've done so far?  or even if this will fix the problem??

Is it something to do with the dashboard?  I have not found another way to upload files and have them linked to the s3 bucket.

I should also add that i don't want users to upload files, this is just me attempting to populate the app with some media files that can be downloaded.

Thanks for any assistance here, this one has been a struggle for me to figure out despite looking for a long long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my IP's abysmal upload speed is responsible for this.

gone back through and cleaned up my changes.  The index.js is the only place that you need to set the maxUploadSize variable.